# How to deploy Angular 9 universal app with firebase functions

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angular9

I recently update to latest angular version 9 and created a app .
I made this app universal using the command :
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
and then i build the app using :
npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr

now dist folder is created with browser and server folder in it but no server.js file was created in dist root directory and also webpack config file was not created when i build the app with angular 9.
Please tell me a way on how can i deploy my new app build on angular 9 universal to firebase cloud functions and hosting

Answer (score 3):

as of angular 9 you will have the following build structure

```
 dist            
  ├── server            
  |    └── main.js and some other files like firebase analytics stuff       
  └── browser                
       └── index.html and all files for the broswer
```

now in order to test this you need to give the following command from your project root dir

```
node dist/server
```

this ll invoke the main.js file in the server folder and you app ll be served locally. info ll be printed on the screen about the localhost url with port.

now in order to deploy to firebase use the following code

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as path from 'path';

const app = require(path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist/server/main")).app; // change the path according to your project structure
const myApp = functions.https.onRequest(app());
```

and you ll have a function myApp where you can access your Angular SSR App

[UPDATE]

there is no fixed place where you initialise your functions. all that matters is that the path of `dist/server/main` is corrent in myApp function

one more thing i forgot to mention is that you have to update your package.json hosting field to the following configuration =>

```
  ...
  "hosting": [{
        "target": "app",
        "public": "/dist/browser", // change it according to your directory structure
        "rewrites": [{
            "source": "**",
            "function": "myApp"
        }]
  }]
  ...
```

hope it helps ;)

Comment: Not working for me, i managed to deploy both hosting and the function but the function runs again and again without end and each time ends in timeout result. can you expline more please?

Comment: i have been in this problem. i need to look into your `main.server.ts` file and also tell be if you can run the local ssr with `node dist/server`

Comment: and for building and running your ssr give this command => `ng build --prod --project={your project name remove the curley braces as well} && ng run {again your project name}:server:production && node dist/server/main.js`.  the reason why i m asking you to do is because i had multiple projects in the same directorry and when i added new project my package.json was messed and was only building my latest app but not the older ones so if you are also have multipple projects use the command. moreover tell me if your build directory structure is same as i have shown in the answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where should I put this function?

Comment: wait i m updating answer

Comment: thanks for you answers, the problem is that everithing run perfectly when i run `firebase serve`, the ssr function start and finish as it should but when i deploy it always timeout, do you have any idea where and what should i search?

Comment: show me your `main.server.ts` i asked about this file before as well but you didnt show me

Comment: @example i wrote a commect below with the file and more explanation

Comment: ok everything is fine if it is working locally then the problem might be in the package.json. did you made the edit i have talked about in the updated answer. you have to write a rewrite field with appropriate values as i have mentioned in the answer. show me your package.json. moreover just try to run the function from url. like => `https://us-central1-{project-id}.cloudfunctions.net/myApp`

Comment: the rewrite is ok, and i also see in the console that the function run when i try to refresh the site on any route that is not the basic route.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211999/discussion-between-lagistos-and-example).

Comment: @example I've added this code and every time when I trying to check my app from incognito tab I have to log in into my Google account

Comment: that's obvious if you close and reopen new incognito tab. i need more details to help you. it ll be better if you open a new question. i ll certainly help ☺️

Comment: @example Checkout my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61307423/i-have-to-log-in-to-view-the-page-angular-9-universal-firebase

Comment: **ng deploy** - brand new - https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/deploy/getting-started.md