# I have to log in to view the page. Angular 9 Universal + Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-universal

I'm using Angular 9 Universal + Firebase. When I use command `npm run build:ssr` I've got one extra file in my dist folder. The file is `dist/server/vendors~firebase-auth.js`. I don't know what does this file do and why I have it but every time when I open my application from incognito window I have to log in via Google or I can't see the page.

Versions:

- "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.1"
- "firebase": "^7.14.1"
- "@angular/fire": "^6.0.0"

I use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440751/how-to-deploy-angular-9-universal-app-with-firebase-functions) to deploy my app. When I inter gmail and password I get this error.

[image]

Comment: are you able to run it locally ? i mean wihtout SSR ?

Comment: @example everything is working fine If I check it with my google account but when I use incognito window I get this error

Comment: do a force reload in both tabs using `chtrl+shift+R` and confirm that it doesnt work in incog while works in nomal window

Comment: It's strange but the main page is working after the force reload and load all articles from database but when I open article page and make a force reload I got 500 error

Comment: its not strange ! thats how browsers work. cache and save users data. now the current problem is in angualr routing i believe. new question basically :)

Comment: @example thank you so much for the answer. I made a little investigation and created following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61314686/why-do-i-get-an-error-with-routing-after-deploying-my-angular-9-firebase-appli