# Why do I get an error with routing after deploying my Angular 9 + Firebase application

Tags: angular, firebase, angular2-routing, angular9

I'm creating Angular 9 Univeral app with Firebase. After the deployment (SSR and non-SSR versions) I started facing the problem:

- when I go to the main route (`/`) and then to any other route -
  everything works fine
- when I open the any route (`/article` for
  example) and then force reload the page (`CTRL + SHIFT + R`) I get an
  500 error

[image]

My `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/dailycoding/browser",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssr"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is an error at the console
[image]

I don't have this error at my local machine and I don't know why it happens at the server. Any advises?

Comment: what are the error showing n the console?

Comment: show your firebase.json

Comment: @varman 500 error when trying to GET

Comment: @example I've added my firebase.json

Comment: You have to clearly explain the error and post error. If other guys don't see this is not clear post, they will ignore. So please post your error that you get in the console. And codes how you navigate

Comment: @varman I've updated my question. Add error screen

Comment: also add the function logs

Comment: i couldn't reply because i was sleeping. our timings are not matching i think 

Comment: @example good morning. Your comments helped me to figure out that I had a problem with my firebase config and my `ssr` function didn't work. I just can't deploy it because of errors.

Comment: is it working now ??

Comment: @example routing is working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had problem with `ssr` cloud function. It didn't deploy because of error so when I changed my `firebase.json` to the following one, my routing started working again.

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/dailycoding/browser",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```